# Filepicker list display of results

Tags: filepicker.io

I am able to add a filepicker.io onto my website but I wish for there to be some sort of result display when the files are uploaded.  Currently I only get a pop up with a statement of the location within filepicker API folder.

Is there a way to list on the website that contains the filepicker the results of the upload?  Like what was uploaded and its size?

Answer (score 0):

You can get information about the uploaded file, such as filename, mimetype, and size, by examining the FPFile object. You can also retrieve the same information and more by using the filepicker.stat() call.